# Does Weak Convergence in $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ imply strong convergence on finite measure subsets?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence weakly convergent to $f$ in $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and $A\subset{\mathbb{R}^{d}}$  being of finite Lebesgue measure. I indicate with $\chi_{A}$ the characteristic function of $A$. Does $\{\chi_{A}f_{n}\}$ strongly converge in $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ or $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$?

Comment: Yes. See Theorem 8.6 (Weak convergence implies strong convergence on small sets)  in *Analysis (2nd Edition)* by Lieb & Loss.

Comment: Or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich–Kondrachov_theorem)

Comment: @Hermès does that theorem have weaker assumptions, right?

Comment: $\chi_A f_n$ isn't even necessarily in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ so something is wrong here.

Comment: Yeah right $L^2$. The theorem in the book of Lieb takes a sequence in $D^1(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ with additional hypotheses. The Lieb's hypotheses are weaker than the one i am assuming, right? So it is direct consequence of this theorem?

Comment: Yes, it works. It's also a consequence of Rellich theorem.

Comment: @Hermès With $A = [0,1]$ and $\phi \in C^\infty_c$ and $e_n = \phi(x) \frac{e^{2i \pi nx}}{\sqrt{1+n^2}}$ doesn't $f_n = e_n$ converge weakly to $0$ in $H^1(\Bbb{R})$ ?

Answer (score 1):

> **Theorem** (Rellich): For any $d>0$ and $s > 0$, the injection
>   $$
> H^s(\mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow L^2(\Omega)
> $$
>   is compact for any Borel-set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ of finite Lebesgue-measure.

Therefore, if $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d$) that converges $H^1$-weakly to $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, then $\{f_n\mathbb{1}_\Omega\}$ converges $L^2(\Omega)$-strongly to $f \mathbb{1}_{\Omega}$.